# Java App Engine - Validate JSON Schema with proper Library

Tags: java, maven, validation, google-app-engine, jsonschema

I'm looking for a valid JsonSchema validation library that could work with App Engine Java environment.

I found 3 different libraries, but none of them is usable for different reasons.

**Number 1: [json-schema-validator](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.kitchen-eel:json-schema-validator)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kitchen-eel</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the code

```
ValidationReport report;
JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromURL(Validator.class.getResource("schema.json"));
JsonNode json = JsonLoader.fromString(input);

JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.defaultFactory();
JsonSchema jsonSchema = factory.fromSchema(schema);

report = jsonSchema.validate(json);

if (!report.isSuccess()) {
    // throw error
}
```

*The problem*: 
It uses an older version of Guava (Guava 13.0.1) that I cannot use because my main project uses the version 19 but more important, I use newer Guava methods that in version 13 did not exists yet

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toImmutableSet()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at org.eel.kitchen.jsonschema.syntax.draftv4.DraftV4TypeSyntaxChecker.<clinit>(DraftV4TypeSyntaxChecker.java:43)
```

---

**Number 2: [org.everit.json.schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the code

```
try (InputStream inputStream =  Validator.class.getResourceAsStream("schema.json")) {
    JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
    Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
    schema.validate(new JSONObject(input)); // throws a ValidationException if this object is invalid
}
```

*The problem*: this library is compiled only for Java 8, which is not available for App Engine environment

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/everit/json/schema/loader/SchemaLoader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

---

**Number 3: [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the code

```
JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromURL(HelloAppEngine.class.getResource("schema.json"));
JsonNode json = JsonLoader.fromURL(HelloAppEngine.class.getResource("json.json"));

JsonSchema jsonSchema = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(schema);
ProcessingReport report = jsonSchema.validate(json);

if (!report.isSuccess()) {
    // throw error;
}
```

*The problem*: It seems that Jackson uses a multi-thread way to execute the code, which in App Engine is forbidden if not declared through GAE ThreadManager

```
java.io.IOException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
```

I did not found other Java implementations for this library, and all my tries was unsuccessful. The only way I made working is the first solution using Guava 13 (I disabled my code, which use newer Guava functions, rewriting the functionality with custom code)

And finally... the question: does anyone have alternative libraries to the one I already shown which might work with App Engine?
If possible, I want avoid downloading the Java8 library and recompile it for 7 version or even update the first library Guava dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want avoid downloading the Java8 library and recompile it for 7

@rduilhe created a backport of the everit library which compiles on java6. You may compile it locally, although it is a port of an earlier version:  https://github.com/rdruilhe/json-schema

(disclaimer: I'm the author of everit-org/json-schema)

Comment: I cloned the repository you gave me but the code contains lamba-functions, so it is clear that is still Java8 code. Is it the 1.1.0 which works with Java6?

Comment: That repo has a branch called "java6-compliant", try that instead of master

Comment: Thank you, found [the section](https://github.com/rdruilhe/json-schema/tree/java6-compliant), downloaded the relative code, configured for my local Maven repository and then deployed. All done and working.